# Unit Test Angular Component Using TemplateRefs

Tags: angular, unit-testing

I'm trying to write unit tests for an Angular component using a `TemplateRef`. Here's the entirety of the component, the TypeScript and the HTML:

```
<!-- alerts-display.component.html -->
<ng-template 
    ngFor 
    let-alert 
    [ngForOf]="alerts$ | async" 
    [ngForTemplate]="alertTemplate">
</ng-template>
```

and

```
export class AlertsDisplayComponent implements OnInit {
    public alerts$: Subject<Alert[]>;
    @ContentChild(TemplateRef)
    alertTemplate: TemplateRef<NgForOfContext<Alert>>;
    constructor(private _alertToaster: AlertToasterService) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.alerts$ = this._alertToaster.alerts$;
    }
}
```

Essentially I'm using the async pipe to subscribe to a Subject from a service that will give me a list of alerts to display, and the end developer can pass in the template for the alert (i.e. could pass a bootstrap alert component, or their own implementation).

I want to write a unit test to make sure that when an alert is added to the subject, an element is output to the page. Here's my unit test code so far:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-test-host',
    template: `
        <hsa-alerts-display>
            <ng-template let-alert>
                <p>{{ alert.message }}</p>
            </ng-template>
        </hsa-alerts-display>
    `,
})
class TestHostComponent {
    @ViewChild(AlertsDisplayComponent) alertsDisplayComponent: AlertsDisplayComponent;
}

describe('AlertsDisplayComponent', () => {
    let component: TestHostComponent;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<TestHostComponent>;
    let mockAlertsToasterService: AlertToasterService;

    beforeEach(async(() => {
        mockAlertsToasterService = jasmine.createSpyObj(['toString']);
        mockAlertsToasterService.alerts$ = new Subject<Alert[]>();
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [AlertsDisplayComponent, TestHostComponent],
            providers: [{ provide: AlertToasterService, useValue: mockAlertsToasterService }],
        }).compileComponents();
    }));

    beforeEach(() => {
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TestHostComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
        fixture.detectChanges();
    });

    it('should show an element for each item in the array list', fakeAsync(() => {
        mockAlertsToasterService.alerts$.next([{ message: 'test message', level: 'success' }]);

        tick();

        const ps = fixture.debugElement.queryAll(By.css('p'));

        expect(ps.length).toBe(1);
    }));
});
```

I created a test host component for the test, and am trying to mock the service to add a message. Then I tried to find the `p` elements via the `fixture`, but that test fails; it gets 0 instead. I have tried a couple different variations of this, but don't know if I'm on the right track or not for sure.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

[Here's a Stackblitz example as well](https://stackblitz.com/edit/alert-toaster-demo).

Answer (score 0):

Everything in my above question is correct, the only thing I missed was to add a `fixture.detectChanges()` after the `tick()` in the last test.

After doing that, the template is updated and the `p` tag that the `TestHostComponent` provided is output and can be found and counted.